# Storing Datetime in a matrix to be used to define points of interest (Python)

Tags: python, loops, pandas, datetime, for-loop

I have bunch of CSV files that contain rows of dates corresponding to data, with column headers Using pandas, I have been able to import the CSV files. Now, I made a CSV file that labels the points of interest by datetime. I have also used pandas to import this file. I need to store the start time and end time in a matrix/array/something to call later to parse with my data which is labeled with these dates. Currently, using pd.to_datetime I have been able to convert the strings in my CSVs to datetime, but I have no idea how to store this. This is my third day using Python, so I apologize for the newbie question. I am a relatively advanced user of Matlab. I will provide my code, but I will not be able to provide the data in question as it is not owned by me. Thanks guys!

```
NUMBER_OF_CLASSES = 4
SUBSPACE_DIMENSION = 3
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sio 
PeriodList = pd.read_csv('IP_List.csv')
PeriodList = PeriodList.as_matrix()

# Pdata format:
# Pdata{hull, engine, 1}(:) - datetime array of hull and engine P data
# Pdata{hull, engine, 2}(:,:) - parametric data corrsponding to timestamps in datetime array 
# Pdata{hull, engine, 3}(:) - array of parametric channel labels 


Pdata_1 = pd.read_csv('LPD-17_1A.csv')
[list_m, list_n] = PeriodList.shape
Pdata_1 = Pdata_1.as_matrix()
startdatetime = []
enddatetime = []
#Up to line 27 done on MatLab script 
for d in range (0, list_m):
    Hull = PeriodList[d,0]
    Engine = PeriodList[d,1]
    startdatetime[d] = pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,2])
    enddatetime[d] =   pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,3])


#startdatetime = pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,2])
```

Comment: Whats the column name of start date and end date

Comment: START for start date and END for end date. However, I have converted IP_List.csv to a matrix to be able to call these values easier. As a matlab guy I really understand the whole concept of looping through rows/columns. In python I am having trouble with storing the "stuff" correctly to be able to access it how I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the dataframe you can store the start and ending dates in a new dataframe and convert the columns to timeseries and then you can access the data by `iloc` method :

```
dates = PeriodList[['START','END']]
dates['START'] =  pd.to_datetime(dates['START'])
dates['END'] =  pd.to_datetime(dates['END'])
# You can access the dates based on index using iloc
dates.iloc[3]
#If you Start date you can use the column name
dates.iloc[3]['START']
```

Incase you want to store specifically under existing data structure, you can use dictionary with key as index and values as dataframe values

```
start_end = dict(zip(dates.index, dates.values))
```

If you are looking for the difference of the end date and start date you can simply subtract the columns i.e

```
dates['Difference'] = dates['END']-dates['START']
```

I suggest you to go through pandas documentation for more info about accessing the data [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

## Edit :

You can also use dictionary in your code i.e

```
startdatetime = {}
enddatetime = {}
#Up to line 27 done on MatLab script 
for d in range (0, list_m):
    Hull = PeriodList[d,0]
    Engine = PeriodList[d,1]
    startdatetime[d] = pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,2])
    enddatetime[d] =   pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,3])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help. I messed around with the iloc method, and I still foresee a problem in that I need to convert the values in the dict to timestamp format in order to compare to other time stamps later on. Unless I am wrong, I do not think comparing dates inputted as strings will work correct? Do you happen to know what I could store the value given by start/enddatetime in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: You can convert the seires to timestamps first and then save the data in their original form in dictionary if you want for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution: Make empty strings, so then the loop stores the value each iteration. Since it is an empty string, there will not be a "cannot convert to float" error. Thanks for the help @Bharath Shetty

Code:

```
PeriodList = pd.read_csv('IP_List.csv')
PeriodList = PeriodList.as_matrix()    
# Pdata format:
# Pdata{hull, engine, 1}(:) - datetime array of hull and engine P data
# Pdata{hull, engine, 2}(:,:) - parametric data corrsponding to timestamps in datetime array 
# Pdata{hull, engine, 3}(:) - array of parametric channel labels 


Pdata_1 = pd.read_csv('LPD-17_1A.csv')
[list_m, list_n] = PeriodList.shape
#Pdata_1 = Pdata_1.as_matrix()
startdatetime = ['' for x in range(list_m)]
enddatetime = ['' for x in range(list_m)]
#Up to line 27 done on MatLab script 
for d in range (0, list_m):
    Hull = PeriodList[d,0]
    Engine = PeriodList[d,1]
    startdatetime[d] = pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,2])
    enddatetime[d] =   pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,3])


#startdatetime = pd.to_datetime(PeriodList[d,2])
```

Comment: You can use dictionary instead of adding strings to a list by list comprehension. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: What are the pros and cons verse the dictionary or list storing in this case. Out of curiosity is one better than the other?

Comment: It saves your time and dictionaries give much more flexibility. If you want u can use `startdatetime.append(data)` instead of creating a list of empty strings.